# Name of a 70s made for tv movie about a futuristic private eye

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think the movie was very early 70s, think Columbo or MacMillan and Wife.   It was about a future private investigator.  He had some quirks for example he still drove a 70s era VW Beetle and he hated technology.  The investigator had a voice activated typewriter, which was just an IBM Selectric typewriter with cheap mike attached.

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is the movie *Computercide* from 1982.  It is a bit later than you listed, but has the scene with the typewriter and microphone.  The following [Site](http://wiki.onemovie.tv/movies/1804786-computercide) shows it at timestamp 4:07.

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083753/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

> The year is 1995 and Michael Stringer is the only private eye left on Earth. One day, he is assigned by a woman to investigate Eden Isle, a complex for people who want a perfect life started by an industrialist named Korter. Interestingly, Korter is found on a beach and is 20 years younger than he was before. When he gets into the complex, he is caught in a web of mystery that he might not get out of. "

I remember Donald Pleasence in this movie stating that the egg had become obsolete because they could raise chickens that could reproduce live offspring. This was a real disappointment to the Detective because he really like eating eggs.

The old car is at 11:02.

[image: Old Car]

[image: Typewriter with Microphone]

Comment: This is exactly the movie.  It looks like it was released in 1977 as Final Eye and then re-released under the name Computercide in 1982.  Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.