# Looking for a late 70s early 80s movie about humans being replaced by robots

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

Started watching a movie as a kid on cable in the late 70s or early 80s about robots replacing human beings. The main character was a private detective. He has an id card/credit card with a single digit number that is overdrawn. At one point he has to scam his way into a "library" to do an Internet type search. He drives a gas powered car when everyone else drives electric cars. That's about all I remember about it.

Comment: The part with the car and private detective is in The Final Eye/Computercide, the time would also fit, but its about clones not robots. But you can have a look at it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKdGEMkodzk, maybe you remember something wrong

Comment: @kl78. The Final Eye/Computercide was my first thought as well.

Comment: see this previous answer for more information on that movie: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94821/name-of-a-70s-made-for-tv-movie-about-a-futuristic-private-eye/94825#94825

Answer (score 3):

As per [Name of a 70s made for tv movie about a futuristic private eye](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94821/name-of-a-70s-made-for-tv-movie-about-a-futuristic-private-eye/94825#94825), this is likely *[Computercide](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083753/)*, aka *The Final Eye*, a 1981 TV movie.

> The year is 1996 and Michael Stringer is the only private eye left on Earth. One day, he is hired by a woman to investigate Eden Isle, a complex for people who want a perfect life started by her industrialist father named Korter. Interestingly, Korter was found on a beach and is 20 years younger than he was before. When Stringer gets into the complex, he is caught in a web of mystery that he might not get out of.

His "Omni Kard" seems to have more than a single digit, but it is declined early in the film when he's parking by the library, which he enters by claiming via intercom to have been accidentally locked out.

[image: Omni Kard declined at the parking meter] [image: Library]

He drives a gasoline car, which indeed contrasts against the futuristic electric cars.

[image: Electric cars] [image: His car]

As noted in the comments, it's not about replacing people with robots, but with clones.